# How to specify JDK version separately for each project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can I use different JDK versions for different projects in Android Studio?
I am using Android Studio 4.2 and unfortunately Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK Location setting is set globally and not per project.

I need to use different JDK versions (namely 8 and 11) in my projects, because one of them is the currently developed app version, which now I had to update to use JDK 11 because of some  requirements, while other projects are previous versions of the same app. I am using those previous app versions when testing app updating processes, checking how things were working before bug introducing changes etc. Because of that I can't simply update those older app versions to use JDK 11.

I thought about providing path to JDK 8 in the project's gradle.properties file, but it states "Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override* any settings specified in this file." and I don't see an option of not specifing any JDK version in Android Studio options.

Comment: When I change Gradle JVM path then this is saved to `.idea/gradle.xml` within the project directory (tested with latest AS 2021.1.1) so I would assume it is project specific.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the comment - indeed in the newest Android Studio JDK is set per project in Gradle's settings. They changed it somewhere between AS 4.2 and AS 2021.1. I didn't want to install newer version just to check that, but with your information I tried it and it works. Strangely, the update didn't break my project for the first time in years :) Main reason why I didn't want to update AS in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the newest Android Studio 2021.1.1 as suggested by Robert in the comment. Indeed it has JDK path configured per project, not globally, as it was in the AS 4.2.

For first time in years updating AS didn't require updating used libraries and other changes in my project, so I will be sticking to 2021.1.1 currently.

And for those, who would prefer to keep on using older version of AS and still be able to use different JDK for different projects: I found out one of solutions is to install second AS application in a separate folder (for example AndroidStudio-jdk8) and choose the right AS installation depending on which JDK is needed for given project.